# BootStrap Modal Can't Close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I open the modal using

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
```

When the modal opens everything has the backdrop color and nothing can be clicked. When I try to click the close button or outside of the modal to close it, nothing happens. I would post the code here, but for some reason it works on jfiddle but not on my system.

Comment: Can you include your html and javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not looking into it sooner, but the z-index was off!